# How can I add an "ALL CATEGORIES" entry in wp_dropdown_categories?

Tags: categories

I want to let the users search posts by categories.
So I use wp_dropdown_categories to build a drop-donw list with all categories.
Trouble is I want to allow them to set this to "ALL CATEGORIES" as well. 
So how can I add another entry in the drop-down list?
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Should be easy to do**
(check the codex: [wp dropdown categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories))

```
<h2><?php _e('Categories:'); ?></h2>
<div>
    <?php wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_all=ALL CATEGORIES&show_count=1&hierarchical=1'); ?>
</div>
```

**p.s**
if you want to wrap with translation this is the way:

```
<h2><?php _e('Categories:'); ?></h2>
<div>
    <?php wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_all='.__('All Categories', 'your_text_domain').'&show_count=1&hierarchical=1'); ?>
</div>
```